# Writing a SQL Server query in a Rails controller

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, database

I am trying to execute a raw SQL query in my rails controller. I tested the query a database program and it works.

Here is my controller (sites_controller.rb):

```
class SitesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @sites = SELECT * FROM "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site WHERE "Number" LIKE 'LA%' OR "Number" LIKE 'LC%'
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@sites) do |site, marker|
      marker.lat site.latitude
      marker.lng site.longitude
    end
  end
end
```

I keep getting this long error message that it is not liking the way I wrote it.

Can anyone help guide me please?

**UPDATE**

My controller has changed to:

```
class SitesController < ApplicationController
  def index
      query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.CpCore_Site WHERE 'Number' LIKE 'LA%' OR 'Number' LIKE 'LC%'"
      @sites = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)

      @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@sites) do |site, marker|
      marker.lat site.latitude
      marker.lng site.longitude

    end
  end
end
```

But now I am getting an error for the site.latitude part which says:

> undefined method `latitude' for 0:Fixnum

latitude is one of columns from the database table that I am trying to extract.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: undefined method `latitude' for 0:Fixnum it's clearly means variable 'site' contain Integer value.

Answer (score 2):

In rails you can't fire query like this. you can do like this

```
query = "SELECT * FROM "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site WHERE "Number" LIKE 'LA%' OR "Number" LIKE 'LC%"
@sites = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

Or

```
@sites = Model.where("Number LIKE 'LA%' OR Number LIKE 'LC%'")
```

Hope this will help you.